# User unable to click button on popup messagebox

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

User unable to click button on popup messagebox .This happen when user machine, install the latest .Net framework 4.5 above

```
public partial class MessageBoxControl
    {
        private static bool _okClicked;
        private static bool _cancelClicked;
        private static bool _yesClicked;
        private static bool _noClicked;
        public static bool IsMsgBoxOpen;
        private static Window _win;
        private static Grid _container;
        private static MessageBoxResult _messageBoxResult;
        private static DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer;
        private static MessageBoxControl _msg;
        public static Action<object, RoutedEventArgs> DefaultAction;
        private static bool _isVerifySelect = false;

        public MessageBoxControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static void OpenControl()
        {

            _msg.GdContainer.Height = 0;
            _msg.GdContainer.Width = 0;
            _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimerOpen_Tick;
            _dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
            _dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }

        public static void CloseControl()
        {
            if (_container != null) _container.IsEnabled = true;
            try
            {
                _dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            }
            catch { }
            _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            _dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimerClose_Tick;
            _dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
            _dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }

        public static void CloseOnEscape()
        {
            CloseControl();
        }

        public static void ExecuteDefaultAction(object obj, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DefaultAction != null)
            {
                DefaultAction(obj, e);
            }
        }

        private static void dispatcherTimerClose_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _msg.MessageContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            _msg.ButtonContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            _msg.ButtonSelect.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            if ((_msg.GdContainer.Height > 0))
            {
                _msg.GdContainer.Height = _msg.GdContainer.Height - 20;
            }

            if ((_msg.GdContainer.Width > 0))
            {
                _msg.GdContainer.Width = _msg.GdContainer.Width - 30;
            }
            else
            {
                _dispatcherTimer.Stop();
                _container.Children.Remove(_msg);
                IsMsgBoxOpen = false;
            }
        }

        private static void dispatcherTimerOpen_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(_msg.GdContainer.Height >= 240))
            {
                _msg.GdContainer.Height = _msg.GdContainer.Height + 20;
            }

            if (!(_msg.GdContainer.Width >= 360))
            {
                _msg.GdContainer.Width = _msg.GdContainer.Width + 30;
            }
            else
            {
                _msg.MessageContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                _msg.ButtonContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                if (_isVerifySelect)
                {
                    _msg.ButtonSelect.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                }

                _dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            }

        }

        public static MessageBoxResult Show(string message,
                                            MessageBoxButton messageBoxButton = MessageBoxButton.OK,
                                            string iconUrl = null, bool isRed = false, Window currentWindow = null,
                                            bool displayCancelOnly = false, UIElement newObject = null, bool isVerify = false)  // testing -- bool displayCancelOnly = false
        {

           // displayCancelOnly = true; // testing
            _isVerifySelect = isVerify;


            if (_msg == null)
            {
                _msg = new MessageBoxControl();

            }

            if (currentWindow != null)
            {
                _win = currentWindow;
            }
            else
            {
                _win = Application.Current.Windows[0];
            }


            if (_win != null)
            {
                _container = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(_win, "GdContainer") as Grid;
                if (_container != null)
                {
                    var msgBox = FindChild<MessageBoxControl>(_container, _msg.Name);
                    if (msgBox == null)
                    {
                        //LoginPage lg = new LoginPage();
                        //if (_win.ToString().Equals(lg.ToString()))
                        //{
                        //    _msg.Margin = new Thickness(40, 0, 0, 0);
                        //    _container.IsEnabled = false;
                        //    _container.Children.Add(_msg);
                        //    IsMsgBoxOpen = true;
                        //}
                        //else
                        //{
                            _msg.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
                            _container.IsEnabled = false;
                            _container.Children.Add(_msg);
                            IsMsgBoxOpen = true;
                        //}
                        //lg.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return MessageBoxResult.Cancel;
                    }

                }
            }
            Panel.SetZIndex(_msg, 1000);
            OpenControl();// To open control in expanding manner
            CommonHelper.PlaypopupSound();
            //_okClicked = false;  // testing
            //_cancelClicked = false; // testing
            //_yesClicked = false; // testing
            //_noClicked = false;  // testing
            //DefaultAction = null; // testing
            _msg.ImgIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            _msg.TxtErrorMessage.Text = message;

            if (newObject != null)
            {
                _msg.TxtErrorMessage.Inlines.Add(newObject);
            }

            if (isRed)
            {
                _msg.TxtErrorMessage.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                _msg.TxtErrorMessage.FontSize = 14;
            }


            if (iconUrl != null)
            {
                _msg.ImgIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(iconUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                _msg.ImgIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }

            if (messageBoxButton == MessageBoxButton.OK)
            {
                _msg.BtnOk.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                if (_isVerifySelect)
                {
                    _msg.BtnOkSelectFinger.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    DefaultAction = _msg.OnOkSelectFingerClick;
                }
                else
                    DefaultAction = _msg.OnOkClick;

                _msg.BtnYes.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                _msg.BtnNo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                _msg.BtnCancel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            }
            if (messageBoxButton == MessageBoxButton.OKCancel)
            {
                _msg.BtnOk.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                _msg.BtnYes.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                _msg.BtnNo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                _msg.BtnCancel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                DefaultAction = _msg.OnOkClick;
            }
            if (messageBoxButton == MessageBoxButton.YesNo)
            {
                _msg.BtnOk.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                _msg.BtnYes.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                _msg.BtnNo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                _msg.BtnCancel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                DefaultAction = _msg.OnYesClick;
            }
            if (messageBoxButton == MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel)
            {
                _msg.BtnOk.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                _msg.BtnYes.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                _msg.BtnNo.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                _msg.BtnCancel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                DefaultAction = _msg.OnYesClick;
            }
            if (displayCancelOnly)
            {
                _msg.BtnOk.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                _msg.BtnYes.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                _msg.BtnNo.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                _msg.BtnCancel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                DefaultAction = _msg.OnOkClick;
            }



            _msg.BtnCancel.ToolTip="Hey";
            _msg.BtnNo.ToolTip = "No";
            _msg.BtnYes.ToolTip = "yes";
            _msg.BtnOk.ToolTip = "ok";
            _msg.BtnNo.ToolTip = "No";

            //if (currentWindow != null)
            //{
            //    _win = currentWindow;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    _win = Application.Current.Windows[0];
            //}

            //_win = Application.Current.Windows[0];
            if (_win != null)
            {
                _container = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(_win, "GdContainer") as Grid; //_win.FindName("GdContainer") as Grid;
                if (_container != null)
                {
                    var msgBox = FindChild<MessageBoxControl>(_container, _msg.Name);
                    if (msgBox == null)
                    {
                        _container.Children.Add(_msg);
                        _msg.Focus();
                        _win.IsEnabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }


            while (!_okClicked && !_yesClicked && !_noClicked && !_cancelClicked)
            {
                // Stop the thread if the application is about to close
                if (_msg.Dispatcher.HasShutdownStarted ||
                    _msg.Dispatcher.HasShutdownFinished)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // Simulate "DoEvents"
                _msg.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Background,
                    new ThreadStart(delegate { }));
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }
            return _messageBoxResult;
        }

        private void OnOkClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _okClicked = true;
            _messageBoxResult = MessageBoxResult.OK;
            CloseControl();
        }

        private void OnYesClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _yesClicked = true;
            _messageBoxResult = MessageBoxResult.Yes;
            CloseControl();
        }

        private void OnNoClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CloseControl();
            _noClicked = true;
            _messageBoxResult = MessageBoxResult.No;

        }

        private void OnCancelClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _cancelClicked = true;
            _messageBoxResult = MessageBoxResult.Cancel;
            CloseControl();
        }

        public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
        where T : DependencyObject
        {
            // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
            if (parent == null) return null;

            T foundChild = null;

            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                // If the child is not of the request child type child
                T childType = child as T;
                if (childType == null)
                {
                    // recursively drill down the tree
                    foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                    // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                    if (foundChild != null) break;
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
                {
                    var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                    // If the child's name is set for search
                    if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                    {
                        // if the child's name is of the request name
                        foundChild = (T)child;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // child element found.
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return foundChild;
        }

        private void OnOkSelectFingerClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            _okClicked = true;
            _messageBoxResult = MessageBoxResult.Yes;
            CloseControl();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Will need more info. You can't click on it? What do you mean?

Comment: Why are you "simulating" DoEvents() instead of using it? This seems to be reason why UI is blocked. Have you already tried System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents() instead?